# Make a dumb TV smart with Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, usb, wifi, streaming-video, android

I have a dumb TV which doesn't play most of the video formats like mkv or mp4. I want to make a system using Raspberry pi so that i can not only connect my pen drive or external hard drive using usb port but also make my tv smart by being able to use apps like youtube, chrome, etc on my TV using Wifi. Also i want to be able to access files or play videos from a pen drive connected to my WiFi Router using USB port on router using Wifi. and Is it possible to do screen mirroring or accessing files or videos from my android phone using wifi on Rasberry Pi. If all this can be done can you please guide me I am doing engineering in electronics and am new to Raspberry Pi. I would like to make this my first DIY project on Raspberry Pi. Please help

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the RPi StackExchange. This question is currently far too broad for our site. You can google for tutorials for Kodi or Rasplex on the RPi, but this question will most likely be closed as is.

Comment: @Jacobm001 i know. But I dont want the whole procedure and how to do it kind of stuff. I am new at Raspberry Pi and this is just a kind of a hobby project for me. All I want is basics and how, where and with what do I start ? I dont want someone to make it for me, all I want is basic idea of how and with what should i start and what parts will I need.. I want to do further research and and the project work myself.

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at some of the many Media Server installations available for the rPi such as [Kodi (formerly XMBC)](http://kodi.tv) or [OpenElec](http://openelec.tv). They give you all your video playing needs. For Android screen mirroring you would need to look for an Android app that does this - [this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=3p8T-Od-Uqk) shows how this is achieved using the YouMap app.

BUT - to be honest, it doesn't make much sense to go through the route of installing one of these distributions when you can do all that you want to do with a [Chromecast dongle](http://google.com/chromecast), which incidentally costs the same as an rPi and works out of the box.

Comment: I know about chromecast but it doesnt support NAS files on my router. And I want to do this as a hobby project to get a good knowledge on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Added a link to a youtube video showing how to do Android screen mirroring.

Comment: Do u know a way by which I can also play videos from NAS pendrive or external hard drive on my router using wifi direct? And which rPi board should i buy for my project and how or with what do i start my project?